# Looking for the splitting field of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_4$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, splitting-field

How to find the degrees of splitting fields of $x^7-1$ and $x^8-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$?

For $x^8-1$ I wrote
$$
x^8-1=(x^2+i)(x+ \sqrt{i})(x- \sqrt{i})(x+i)(x-i)(x+1)(x-1),
$$
but I'm not sure what to do with $(x^2+i)$...
Is there a brutal force for this kind of problem?

Comment: With $n= p^k m, p\nmid m$ then the splitting field of $x^n-1=(x^m-1)^{p^k}\in F_p[x]$ is $F_{p^f}$ where $f$ is the order of $p \bmod m$. Proof : $F_{p^f}^*$ is cyclic with $p^f-1$ elements.

Comment: $\Bbb F_4$ is a field of characteristic $2$. In such a field, the identity $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$ holds.

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb F_4$, $1+1=2=0$ and $-1=1-2=1$. Therefore
$$(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1=x^2-1.$$
So,
$$(x-1)^4=(x^2-1)^2=x^4-1$$
and
$$(x-1)^8=(x^4-1)^2=x^8-1.$$

Comment: By $\mathbb{F}_4$ I meant the field of $4$ elements, why is $2=0$?

Comment: $\Bbb F_2$ generally means the field of two elements. @beigecamellia

Comment: No I wrote $\mathbb{F}_4$ in the original question

Comment: And you originally wrote "$F_2$" in your comment @beigecamellia

Comment: Yes but I wrote $\mathbb{F}_4$ in the original question so I was wondering why did you say "in $ \mathbb{F_4}$, $1+1 = 2 =0$"

Comment: I know $2=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_2$ but why in $\mathbb{F}_4$?

Comment: $\Bbb F_4$ is an extension field of $\Bbb F_2$. @beigecamellia